# Poisson distribution squared

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Let $X$ be a poisson distributed r.v. of parameter $\lambda>0$. Then for any integer $k \geq 0$ is it correct that $$P(X^2=k)=P(X=\sqrt{k})=\lambda^{\sqrt{k}} e^{-\lambda}/\sqrt{k}!$$

where for $\sqrt{k}!$ I mean $\sqrt{k}!= \Gamma (\sqrt{k})$ ?

Comment: Since X takes values on integers, X^2 is a square, so it is clearer to write P(X^2=n^2) to start with. You never have to use the Gamma function explicitly

Comment: So to be explicit: no, it is not correct, if $k$ is not a square. If $k$ is not a square, then $\sqrt{k}$ is not an integer, and so $P(X=\sqrt{k})$ is equal to $0$, rather than to the expression that you give.